# How can I cleanly remove Workspaces in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm on a MAC and remove workspaces with the terminal in the folder **~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage**, but i don't think it's the clean way.

Can someone explain me how I can remove cleanly a workspace and all its files from my mac?

I miss this feature. I can add many workspaces, but where is the "delete button"?

I use Visual Studio Code V.1.28.2 on macOS Mojave 10.14.

Comment: How do you add workspaces? I have not been able to figure this one out.

Comment: Just add a Folder and save as Workspace. ;)

Answer (score 43):

You can use the command palette:

> Menu: View > Command Palette... (or F1)

Search: "**Workspaces: Remove Folder from Workspace...**" and select the folder you want to remove.

[image: Workspaces:Remove Folder from Workspace...]

Hope this may help you

Comment: Thanks, very convenient!  I just add for non-experienced VS users.  Cmd+Shift+P (launch Command Palette) and then type the search string.  The search engine is good, so the query may not start from "Workspaces: [...]".

Answer (score 16):

Visual Studio Code 1.32.3. Windows 10.

Here's the answer from the Twitter account of Visual studio code:

[image: From Twitter]

You have just to go to the Explorer section and remove any folder or file in it see the image below:

[image: Image 2]

right click in the workspace you'd like to remove and select the "Remove Folder from Workspace" item; the name of the workspace will become: "NO FOLDER OPENED" that is the one you'll get when you installed the very first time Visual Studio Code.

[image: Default]

Comment: There is no such menu in my latest version.  I get "open editors", "outline", "hide", etc.  No way but to shut down VSC and re-open a "new window" instance.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work on VSC Version: 1.47.3 on MacOS.  See the thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/59896610/5028342

Answer (score 6):

If none of the above solutions works ...you can go to file -> close folder.

It will close the workspace folder and you can add any new folder to the explorer, like the first time you install visual code

[image: here is description image]

Comment: Close <> remove.

Answer (score 5):

find workspace.json, it will be inside the workspace you had created workspaces->[unique number]->workspace.json . you can edit the workspace directories in it.

Answer (score 5):

The only other relevant answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55171434/12669337) .

The Workspaces is stored at `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage` (Windows) , none of the mentioned actions will delete them .

There also can be a `.code-workspace` Workspace File or "Workspace Config" , which can be moved anywhere . And `.vscode` Workspace Folder/-s in the folder/-s which was added to the workspace .

Deleting all existing of these 3, and the relevant items from : `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\storage.json` and all `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\logs<< .. >>` . Will be a workspace deletion .

Also, when the same Workspace File is opened from different location, it seems that a new Workspace is created at the `workspaceStorage` , so there would be 2 related Workspaces .

Answer (score 1):

It seems that workspaces are either open or closed, you can close them from the main menu. To cleanly delete a workspace, just remove the workspace file from disk also.

Comment: Is the folder I Posted the only place?

Comment: Please Point directly where it Is.  I didnt found a remove workspace in Main Menu.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a Java application, you can use the command (ctrl-shift-P) "clean java language server workspace"